Image not found in Vue built library
I want to compile a Vue library, my lib structure is something like this:
mod
  lib1
    vue
      lib1.vue
    assets
      image1.png

I am referencing an image in lib1.vue:
# lib1.vue
<template>
  <img src="../assets/image1.png" />
</template>

I compiled it:
yarn build --target lib --name lib1 --dest dist/lib1 --no-clean --mode production --inline-vue mod/lib1/vue/lib1.vue

Then included it on a page:
<html>
<body>
<div id="lib1"></div>

<script>
  (function () {
    import('./dist/lib1/lib1.umd.js')
      .then(() => {
        window.lib1.default('#lib1');
      });
  })();
</script>

Returns error "image1.hashhash.png 404 (Not Found)" because it is referred as "img/image1.hashhash.png" but should be referred as "lib1/img/image1.hashhash.png".
How can I supply base path for assets in my library? Or am I doing this fundamentally wrong? Might as well be, I'm new to Vue.
Vue v3.5
